# Open Source Tool For Running My Automated Tests

Tags: build-automation

I would like to know a best Open Source Tool that I can use to manage and maintain automation testing for every build and every product release.

Basically, during every build, I would like to click on a link which should trigger all my test cases. Then, it should generate a link with build number and list out the number of failures and passes and have a link to them to get more details, etc.

I have a framework setup already in Selenium WebDriver with TestNG, Eclipse, & with Java Programming Language.

Earlier, we used Atlassian Bamboo for our other product, but we don't use it more.

I hope I am clear on what I am looking for.

Thanks,
Alok

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at a build server like TeamCity or Jenkins.   They are both free for commercial use with an optional "enterprise"  license that can be purchased to provide additional support and functionality but they are not open source.   I have been using TeamCity for about a year and it has given me no problems.   See URLs below:

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity
 http://jenkins-ci.org/